# Frequent "Exception: boost::wrapexcept<boost::bad_weak_ptr>" stack trace in logs

Tags: daemon, cryptonote, error-log, protocol

I recently started running a Monero daemon, and while it seems to be working, I get a stack trace like this about every 30 seconds in the logs:

```
2021-06-19 03:52:18.960 [P2P0]  INFO    stacktrace  src/common/stack_trace.cpp:133  Exception: boost::wrapexcept<boost::bad_weak_ptr>
2021-06-19 03:52:18.960 [P2P0]  INFO    stacktrace  src/common/stack_trace.cpp:134  Unwound call stack:
2021-06-19 03:52:18.965 [P2P0]  INFO    stacktrace  src/common/stack_trace.cpp:172      [1]  0x119) [0x297a344f0c8]:__cxa_throw+0x119) [0x297a344f0c8]
2021-06-19 03:52:18.965 [P2P0]  INFO    stacktrace  src/common/stack_trace.cpp:172      [2] /usr/bin/monerod(+0x2ec2ad) [0x297a34272ad] 
2021-06-19 03:52:18.965 [P2P0]  INFO    stacktrace  src/common/stack_trace.cpp:172      [3]  0x84) [0x297a384a8c4]:_ZN4epee9net_utils10connectionINS_5levin22async_protocol_handlerIN8nodetool24p2p_connection_context_tIN10cryptonote29cryptonote_connection_contextEEEEEE21safe_shared_from_thisEv+0x84) [0x297a384a8c4]
2021-06-19 03:52:18.965 [P2P0]  INFO    stacktrace  src/common/stack_trace.cpp:172      [4]  0x3a) [0x297a384a94a]:_ZN4epee9net_utils10connectionINS_5levin22async_protocol_handlerIN8nodetool24p2p_connection_context_tIN10cryptonote29cryptonote_connection_contextEEEEEE7add_refEv+0x3a) [0x297a384a94a]
2021-06-19 03:52:18.965 [P2P0]  INFO    stacktrace  src/common/stack_trace.cpp:172      [5]  0xa0) [0x297a3832c00]:_ZN4epee5levin22async_protocol_handlerIN8nodetool24p2p_connection_context_tIN10cryptonote29cryptonote_connection_contextEEEE16start_outer_callEv+0xa0) [0x297a3832c00]
2021-06-19 03:52:18.965 [P2P0]  INFO    stacktrace  src/common/stack_trace.cpp:172      [6]  0x11c2) [0x297a38bb872]:_ZN8nodetool11node_serverIN10cryptonote29t_cryptonote_protocol_handlerINS1_4coreEEEE33make_new_connection_from_peerlistERNS5_12network_zoneEb+0x11c2) [0x297a38bb872]
2021-06-19 03:52:18.965 [P2P0]  INFO    stacktrace  src/common/stack_trace.cpp:172      [7]  0x5cd) [0x297a38bd9ad]:_ZN8nodetool11node_serverIN10cryptonote29t_cryptonote_protocol_handlerINS1_4coreEEEE31make_expected_connections_countERNS5_12network_zoneENS5_8PeerTypeEm+0x5cd) [0x297a38bd9ad]
2021-06-19 03:52:18.965 [P2P0]  INFO    stacktrace  src/common/stack_trace.cpp:172      [8]  0x469) [0x297a38bf7f9]:_ZN8nodetool11node_serverIN10cryptonote29t_cryptonote_protocol_handlerINS1_4coreEEEE17connections_makerEv+0x469) [0x297a38bf7f9]
2021-06-19 03:52:18.965 [P2P0]  INFO    stacktrace  src/common/stack_trace.cpp:172      [9]  0xac) [0x297a38151bc]:_ZN8nodetool11node_serverIN10cryptonote29t_cryptonote_protocol_handlerINS1_4coreEEEE11idle_workerEv+0xac) [0x297a38151bc]
2021-06-19 03:52:18.965 [P2P0]  INFO    stacktrace  src/common/stack_trace.cpp:172      [10]  0x5a) [0x297a38619aa]:_ZN4epee9net_utils18boosted_tcp_serverINS_5levin22async_protocol_handlerIN8nodetool24p2p_connection_context_tIN10cryptonote29cryptonote_connection_contextEEEEEE20global_timer_handlerIN5boost3_bi6bind_tIbNSC_4_mfi3mf0IbNS4_11node_serverINS6_29t_cryptonote_protocol_handlerINS6_4coreEEEEEEENSD_5list1INSD_5valueIPSL_EEEEEEEEbNSC_10shared_ptrINSA_20idle_callback_conextIT_EEEE+0x5a) [0x297a38619aa]
2021-06-19 03:52:18.965 [P2P0]  INFO    stacktrace  src/common/stack_trace.cpp:172      [11]  0x2c4) [0x297a3861734]:_ZN5boost4asio6detail12wait_handlerINS_3_bi6bind_tIbNS_4_mfi3mf1IbN4epee9net_utils18boosted_tcp_serverINS7_5levin22async_protocol_handlerIN8nodetool24p2p_connection_context_tIN10cryptonote29cryptonote_connection_contextEEEEEEENS_10shared_ptrINSI_20idle_callback_conextINS4_IbNS5_3mf0IbNSC_11node_serverINSE_29t_cryptonote_protocol_handlerINSE_4coreEEEEEEENS3_5list1INS3_5valueIPSQ_EEEEEEEEEEEENS3_5list2INST_IPSI_EENST_ISZ_EEEEEENS0_15any_io_executorEE11do_completeEPvPNS1_19scheduler_operationERKNS_6system10error_codeEm+0x2c4) [0x297a3861734]
2021-06-19 03:52:18.965 [P2P0]  INFO    stacktrace  src/common/stack_trace.cpp:172      [12] /usr/bin/monerod(+0x6c0a06) [0x297a37fba06] 
2021-06-19 03:52:18.965 [P2P0]  INFO    stacktrace  src/common/stack_trace.cpp:172      [13]  0x266) [0x297a383d826]:_ZN4epee9net_utils18boosted_tcp_serverINS_5levin22async_protocol_handlerIN8nodetool24p2p_connection_context_tIN10cryptonote29cryptonote_connection_contextEEEEEE13worker_threadEv+0x266) [0x297a383d826]
2021-06-19 03:52:18.965 [P2P0]  INFO    stacktrace  src/common/stack_trace.cpp:172      [14]  0xac07) [0x667ab7c12c07]:_thread.so.1.76.0(+0xac07) [0x667ab7c12c07]
2021-06-19 03:52:18.965 [P2P0]  INFO    stacktrace  src/common/stack_trace.cpp:172      [15] /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0(+0x9259) [0x667ab7833259] 
2021-06-19 03:52:18.965 [P2P0]  INFO    stacktrace  src/common/stack_trace.cpp:172      [16] /usr/lib/libc.so.6(clone+0x43) [0x667ab775c5e3] 
2021-06-19 03:52:18.965 [P2P0]  INFO    stacktrace  src/common/stack_trace.cpp:172
```

To me, this looks like something is going awfully wrong, but similar reports I found seem to indicate that exceptions like this are normal and to just ignore them.

So, is there anything to worry about here? Anything I could do to prevent these exceptions? Or if it's a useless warning, any way to exclude it from the logs?

I tried `MONERO_RANDOMX_UMASK=1` in the env and `vm.nr_hugepages=1280` in sysctl, to no avail.

It seems this could be a bug but I can't report this on their github because I haven't contributed before.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing seems to be amiss. You can run with --log-level 0,stacktrace:FATAL if you want to get rid of those for space reasons. Ideally the error handling should be less noisy. It was supposed to have been fixed a year ago by https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/6269 but evidently something else changed since to make it noisy again.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  So, this exception simply indicates that a connection to some peer failed or was interrupted?
I'm not concerned about the space, but don't want to miss important errors which is hard when the log is full of these.

Comment: It indicates a connection was closed, so an operation cannot be performed on it. To see errors: grep ERROR bitmonero.log

Comment: Thanks again, very helpful. I suppose a new "less noisy logs" issue should be opened then, but I'm not sure where to report issues, is this it?

Comment: There already is such an issue IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude lines with 'grep -v' to clearly read the log:

```
cat /var/log/monero/monerod.log | grep -v 'stacktrace'
```